# The running time complexity of BFS for unconnected and indirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I know that for a connected indirected graph, the running time for the BFS is O(V+E). But what if the graph is not connected? Then I assume we need to run a loop to check each vertex's condition first (visited or not).

Here is the simple qseudocode for my idea. Assume every vertex has color white as the sign of not visited at beginning. Gray as visited, black as taken.

//BFS for unconnected indirection graph

```
BFS(G):   
for each v in G:
    if (v.color is white) do:
        v.color = gray;
        enqueue(Q, v);
        while Q is not empty do:
            u = dequeue(Q);
            while s is adjacent to u has color white
                  s.color = gray;
                  enqueue(Q,s);
            u.color = black;
```

This is my guess of qseudocode for the unconnected indirected graph. I am having trouble to figure out the running time. I think it is still O(V + E), but I cannot really give a reasonable explanation.

May I know how to clarify the running time of this qseudocode? Or if my qseudocode is inefficient, please let me know an efficient one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the time complexity is still `O(V + E)`.

Just check each loop and the maximum number of times it can possibly run.

The outer loop will have `O(V)` steps.

The loop checking queue will also have `O(V)` steps as each node in the graph is only being inserted in the queue once (when it was colored white).

The tricky part is the third loop checking adjacent nodes of `u`. Note that we have already established that `u` will represent each node in the graph exactly once. If you are using an adjacency list for graph representation, this step will take `O(E)` time.

Total time complexity: `O(V + E)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct. The outer loop iterates over all vertices at most once so is in `O(|V|)`. The inner portion is the BFS for connected graphs, that is `O(|V|+|E|)`. Then, overall it stays in `O(|V|+|E|)` since you look at every vertex and every edge at most `O(1)` times.

As a more general explanation, in the graph you have a linear number of vertices but you can have a quadratic number of edges, think about a [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph). So, if the graph is disconnected you simple have less edges to traverse.